# Elixir: def structs with fields as lists of another struct type

Tags: struct, elixir

If I have the following struct:

```
defmodule Events.InviteEvent do
  defstruct [
    :event_id,
    :invite_list
  ]
end
```

Is it possible to define the :invite_list to be a list of which has a type of another struct ? Basically I would like to define a struct with the following structure:

```
{
event_id: 123,
invite_list: [
              {name: "jason", email: "myemail1@email.com"},
              {name: "judy", email: "myemail2@email.com"}
              ]
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification, the `:invite_list` key is not a list of structs. That is a list of tuples. Also, I'm not really sure what you are sking here. Elixir does not have a real type system. You can just put whatever data you want into your structs.

Comment: And I noticed after my initial comment that is also invalid syntax (for the tuples).

Answer (score 3):

From [Structs](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html):

> Structs provide *compile-time* guarantees that only the fields (and *all* of them) defined through `defstruct` will be allowed to exist in a struct

The only guarantee you get is that the field names are present. There is no way to specify the type of the values.

You could write a helper function to build your struct that uses [typespecs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html), but that doesn't give you any extra compile-time or run-time guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, I often add lists to my struct. So assuming you had an %Invite{} struct, I would write something like the following:

```
defmodule Events.InviteEvent do

  defstruct [
    event_id: nil,
    invite_list: []
  ]

end
```

Then populate as you want.

```
%Events.InviteEvent{
  event_id: 123, 
  invite_list: [
    %Invite{name: "jason", email: "myemail1@email.com"}, 
    %Invite{name: "judy", email: "myemail2@email.com"}
  ]
```

If you need to be careful that invite_list only contains a list of %Invite{}, then manage that with the interface to your struct.